# serialize and deserialize between 2 classes

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to implement the following structure into my program:

```
    public abstract class A extends Service {

    public abstract void getData();

    //variables
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    mHandler.postDelayed(1*1000, mHandler);
    return START_STICKY;
    }

    public Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {

    AnotherClass ac = new AnotherClass();
    ac.method();

    // AnotherClass implements Serializable and stores all data.

    A start = new B();
//Start abstract method getData defined in class B
    start.getData();
    mHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 1 * 1000);
    }
    };
    }
```

Now B is a class which extends A.

```
public class B extends A {

public void getData() {

//Here I need to fetch the data from ac(AnotherClass) object which was serialized.

//perform my activity.

}
}
```

I'm new to this serializable concept. Can I use this to implement the above structure?? Also, can i serialize the contents of ac object into a vector?? Please guide me through, an example would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm) of serialization and deserialization for you.

Comment: I don want to use a file over here. I'm asking for the alternative here. Can i use a vector or any other??

Comment: why do you need to serialize it ? there are so many other alternatives to communicate between classes. Use a static vector atleast.

Comment: Like B class, I've sevaral classes which extends A, performs different activities in getData() function. So, it requires different attributes from A. I cant call getData from A with different arguments for all of these classes. Thus I need to generalize. I call getData() from A. Other classes gets data by deserializing and performs its operations.

Comment: You can't serialize into a vector or something. Serializing is for files.
Also I am not sure that i understand what functionality you are trying to achieve here. Please be clearer

Comment: U can use Serializable on ByteArrayOutputStream and ByteArrayInputStream. File isnt compulsory for Serializable.